# MySQL query for insert

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert into my MYSQL database but my code always go to the catch section (which says uploading to database failed). What am I doing wrong?

```
public static Connection getAttConnection() throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "VB";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "***********";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
    return conn;
}

public static void addAttendance(String name, String type, String size,
    String path, String last_Mod) {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    boolean committed = false;
    try {
        conn = getAttConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        String query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, path, last_Mod) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1,name);
        pstmt.setString(2,type);
        pstmt.setString(3,size);
        pstmt.setString(4,path);
        pstmt.setString(5,last_Mod);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        committed = true;
        System.out.println("Upload Correctly");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Uploading to database failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you print the stacktrace instead of displaying custom message?

Comment: Try to print the StackTrace in catch to see the error

Comment: print the stacktrace from the exception and post it here `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Going forward you should try to log *real* error information somewhere. The "Uploading to database failed" is exactly what you want to show the user (not too much detail), but for yourself you should record the stack trace and the `e.getMessage()`. Better yet, `catch` a `SQLException` and record `e.getErrorCode()`, `e.getMessage()`, and the stack trace. If there's a problem you'll have accurate diagnostic information.

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea how people can come up with a solution to an unknown problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your password supplied correctly? Your code shows its all "***"

Next, check the Database name.

Then, instead of printing a custom message, print the entire exception, like this:

```
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure but you are probably inserting strings without quotes....

```
String query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, path, 
               last_Mod) VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?')";
```

You are passing all the parameters as strings, but I suspect size should be an int.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there might be a problem with data types, e.g. when you do

```
pstmt.setString(3, size);
```

Are you sure that `size` is a String in your database table?

Also, please add

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

to your `catch()` clause to get a more detailed error message.

Comment: He is talking about the TYPE in DB table , not Java type!